# googleimagesdownloadで画像がダウンロードされない

Tags: shellscript

Macの`Create ML`で画像分類のモデルを作ろうとしています。
`googleimagesdownload`を使用してトレーニング画像をダウンロードしようとしています。
コマンドを実行したところ、

```
shuntaro@air5 traningData % googleimagesdownload -k "リンゴ"

Item no.: 1 --> Item name = \u30ea\u30f3\u30b4
Evaluating...
Could not open URL. Please check your internet connection and/or ssl settings 
If you are using proxy, make sure your proxy settings is configured correctly
```

と表示され、`downloads`ディレクトリが作成されるだけで画像はダウンロードされません。
インターネットも`Wi-fi`で普通につながっていますし、問題なく使えているので、何をしたらいいかがわかりません。
わかる方、遭遇したが解決した方、回答お願いします。

**追記:**
日本語だからできないのかと思いましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
shuntaro@air5 traningData % googleimagesdownload -k red Apple

Item no.: 1 --> Item name = red Apple
Evaluating...
Could not open URL. Please check your internet connection and/or ssl settings 
If you are using proxy, make sure your proxy settings is configured correctly
```

Comment: 念の為、外部とのネットワーク接続にプロキシを通す必要がある環境だったりしませんか？

Comment: いいえ。違います。